# How to find a string in result of an unix script

Tags: shell, grep

I have script named "sample.sh" which contains list of file names with their details. The file names are file1.txt, file1.dat,..etc

sample.sh contains

```
<Contents>
   <Key>text1.dat</Key>
   <LastModified>date</LastModified>
   <Name>fjhdgfjsd</Name>
</Contents>
<Contents>
   <Key>text2.dat</Key>
   <LastModified>date</LastModified>
   <Name>fd-datastage</Name>
</Contents>
```

I want to find the count of .dat files or .txt files.
I used below command. It is working as expected.

```
sh sample.sh | grep ".dat"
```

But I am also getting results for -dat and .dat lines. Output contains

```
<Key>text1.dat</Key>
<Key>text2.dat</Key>
<Name>fd-datastage</Name>
```

But I want sorted output on LastModified when i run sample.sh
Please suggest any commands.

Comment: what is the output of `grep -o .dat sample.sh`?  Does it output all files which end by .dat and nothing else?  If not, what does it output?

Comment: you should include a small example of sample.sh for which all of your commands provide incorrect results, and what is the correct result for this sample.sh .  To obtain the small example of sample.sh, start with your sample.sh and remove lines.

Comment: @Shanti: Could you please provide the sample input or how does your `sample.sh` script looks like, so that we can help.

Comment: Updated script @user31264

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
grep '\.dat\>' sample.sh | less
```

If it prints only the lines you need, then your solution is

```
grep -c '\.dat\>' sample.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "\.dat\|\.txt" sample.sh |wc -l
```

This should give you the total count of .dat and .txt file.